# Websphere Liberty in eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, websphere

I am trying to add db2Datasource and oracle datasource via server.xml for websphereliberty but it is showing some error while starting the server.

The error is :

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [jsp-2.3, servlet-3.1, jndi-1.0, localConnector-1.0, el-3.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server WebServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0042E: A feature definition cannot  be found for the  jdbc-4.0 feature.  Try running the command, bin/installUtility install jdbc-4.0,  to install the feature. Alternatively, you can run the command, bin/installUtility install WebServer,  to install all features that are referenced by this configuration.
[ERROR   ] CWPKI0033E: The keystore located at F:/WGD/Dep 497281-DSA_JAVA/kashish/softwares/WEB server/usr/servers/WebServer/resources/security/key.jks did not load because of the following error: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
[WARNING ] CWPKI0809W: There is a failure loading the defaultKeyStore keystore. If an SSL configuration references the defaultKeyStore keystore, then the SSL configuration will fail to initialize.  
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 16,199 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [ssl-1.0, distributedMap-1.0, appSecurity-2.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 16,092 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server WebServer stopped after 2 minutes, 14,767 seconds.
********************************************************************************
product = WebSphere Application Server 16.0.0.2 (wlp-1.0.13.cl160220160526-2258)
wlp.install.dir = F:/WGD/Dep 497281-DSA_JAVA/kashish/softwares/WEB server/
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101
java.version = 1.8.0_101
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.8.0_101-b13)
os = Windows 7 (6.1; amd64) (en_US)
process = 6772@NLVHPRAAB00868
********************************************************************************
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server WebServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/16.0.0.2/lafiles/en.html
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0042E: A feature definition cannot  be found for the  jdbc-4.0 feature.  Try running the command, bin/installUtility install jdbc-4.0,  to install the feature. Alternatively, you can run the command, bin/installUtility install WebServer,  to install all features that are referenced by this configuration.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[ERROR   ] CWWKE0702E: Could not resolve module: com.ibm.ws.transaction.cdi [49]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.tx.jta; version="[2.1.0,3.0.0)"

[ERROR   ] CWWKE0702E: Could not resolve module: com.ibm.ws.jca [73]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.tx.jta; version="[2.1.0,3.0.0)"

[ERROR   ] CWWKE0702E: Could not resolve module: com.ibm.ws.jca-1.7 [76]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.ws.jca.cm

[ERROR   ] CWWKE0702E: Could not resolve module: com.ibm.ws.app.manager.rar [77]
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is this error message:

[ERROR   ] CWWKF0042E: A feature definition cannot  be found for the  jdbc-4.0 feature.  Try running the command, `bin/installUtility install jdbc-4.0`,  to install the feature. Alternatively, you can run the command, `bin/installUtility install WebServer`,  to install all features that are referenced by this configuration.

Comment: Hmm.. I dont remember any webServer feature in Liberty..., so probably a typo :-)

Comment: That is the server name. It is an inserted value, IIRC

Answer (score 1):

Since Liberty 16.0.0.2 by default has only Java EE 7 features, you either need to use `jdbc-4.1` feature, or install `jdbc-4.0` as ebullient suggested.

I'd suggest just changing to 4.1 :-)

If you need more older features (from Java EE 6), I'd suggest to install either `webProfile-6.0` feature or `baseBundle` add on. Both can be installed with `installUtility`.